# remove lines in bash on long running app by using regex

Tags: bash, grep

I have an commandline bash file that I execute in Teamcity. Because execution causes allot of clutter, I want to remove lines to clean it up a bit.

This is a output of the bash file. When uploading a file, it shows a loader from 0% to 100% with color chars

```
[==================================================>] 100% [2K
[==================================================>] 100%
[==================================================>] 100% [2K
[==================================================>] 100% [2K
[==================================================>] 100%
```

What i've tried is to remove the chars. But there is no output

```
./run.sh |  grep '(.*)2K' | grep '(.*)\%'
```

when I use `tee /dev/stdout` it shows duplicates

```
./run.sh | grep '(.*)2K' | grep '(.*)\%' | tee /dev/stdout
```

The executable that outputs the loading line is https://github.com/balena-io/balena-cli

Comment: Might be a buffering issue, try `--line-buffered` if  your grep supports it. For the regex? wiktor-stribiżew has your back! -:)

Comment: Well, ``| tee /dev/stdout`` means "I want to duplicate everything". So it works as expected I would say.

Comment: Why did you add that ``tee /dev/stdout``?

Comment: For the main problem, hard to say with no knowledge of what run.sh does. But I suspect it is a dynamic thing, that redraws the bar constantly (with \r). So, grep waits to have complete lines (which it doesn't most of the time, since, there is no \n). Plus, most tools that output strings won't flush stdout before they output a \n. So hard to say more. But those dynamic things full of \r and even \033[ codes, are not and ideal playground for line processing tools like grep, and like most of usual scripting tools (awk, sed, ...)

Comment: The `[2K` look like half of ANSI escape code.

Comment: @chrslg thanks for the answers. Yes the `tee` is bad, but I hoped that it would solve the issue I've added more info regarding the content of bash file. When I `| grep  --line-buffered -wv  "==="`  on `rsync` console shows info. But yes, it could that the cli that I use in the bash file doesn't flush

Comment: what program outputs the progress meter ? rsync ?

Comment: Many programs allow you to disable the display of a progress meter; perhaps look into that instead?

Comment: If the idea is to still show the bars, while removing escape codes... I had quite similar problem once. But I dealt with in C. Not that you could not do it with any language able to read from stdin and write to stdout (so, basically, any language). But this is a byte per byte thing. And reading stdin byte per byte, parsing it, to write byte per byte output is not especially what bash is good for.

Comment: @chrslg Yes, i'm going to  move to python to remove the lines. I see no other option.

Comment: @LeGEC No balena-cli. See link.